# Can I statically link to dbghelp. What are the licensing consequences?

Tags: visual-c++, dbghelp

I need to statically link dbghelp.lib to my VS C++ application in order to obtain a dump on crash from customer machines. We have a thoroughly nonsensical requirement that the application must be a single executable file with no installation required. That is the reason I do not dynamically link to dbghelp.dll, as that would be another file to include.

Can I legally do this? Am I running afoul of some arcane EULA somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not fully understand what "statically linking dbghelp.lib" meant. I'm still using the dll, and that's included in Windows, so there is no additional redistribution.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/132fab64-e1a3-456d-959a-b2e177a271f7/can-i-statically-link-dbghelplib-and-distribute-my-c-application?forum=windbg